# Error installing rootpy: ROOT cannot be imported. Is ROOT installed with PyROOT enabled?

Tags: pyroot, rootpy

I am a 10.13.4 Mac user and I have ROOT 6.14.00 installed from running the dmg file downloaded from https://root.cern.ch/content/release-61400. I then tried to install rootpy by

> sudo pip install rootpy

it gives me the error

> ROOT cannot be imported. Is ROOT installed with PyROOT enabled?
>
> ---
>
> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-install-Idx6tf/rootpy/

I do not know what is going on, but I see the root_v6.14.00 lying in Application/ folder (and I see documentation says that pyROOT is on by default), and I have python 2.7.10 installed on my Mac. There seem to be no documentation online for solving this issue. I wonder if anyone knows what is going on or am I better off install rootpy on ubuntu on a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you might have a local installation of ROOT. If you don't want to install ROOT system wide, you can install rootpy for your user only:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

If this is not what you want, you can login as root using `sudo su`, then export what is in `thisroot.sh` from wherever your ROOT installation is:

```
source path_to_root/bin/thisroot.sh
```

Then you can install `rootpy` system-wide executing `python setup.py install`, without logging out as root.